# Edit source differs from question view? Or are we each other's friends now?

Tags: support

I stumbled upon the following issue. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870062/cuda-compiling-error) starts out with "Dear friends", as can be seen in the image below (and hopefully by following the link).

[image: I'm not your friend]

However, when I go to edit the question for some clean-up, I don't see this in the source of the question:

[image: Hmm, apparently I'm really not your friend]

My first guess was that a suggested edit is hanging around somewhere, but I don't see one. So, what's going on? Am I the only one seeing this? Bug? Cache? (New feature? Are we all friends now? ;) )

Comment: That **is** peculiar...

Comment: I'll be your friend ^_^

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA Thank you for answering my real question. ;)

Comment: None of the [revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4870062/revisions) of the question contains the words you see.

Comment: @kiamlaluno That's the weird thing. It seems Cody Gray did something to fix it, but it was truly there. (Why do I hear Twilight Zone music?)

Comment: Bah! Sorry I plundered your question here. That "Dear friends" was bothering me, I swear it was there when I saw the question.

Comment: What Cody did was to fix the spelling of some words (e.g. capitalizing some words); the [original post](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/382692ac-8ecc-4bd6-8c5a-9f2de82fe277/view-source) doesn't contain the words "Dear friends"; the question starts with, "i write my first CUDA code as follows:" The question is one year old; it's not a case of editing done in the grace period.

Comment: Odd.... :-\ I tried repro'ing it but to no avail.

Comment: @kiamlaluno ...and yet Cody Gray says he saw it and it was bothering him. I have better things to do than to make this stuff up.

Comment: I didn't say you made stuff up. I just said that what Stack Overflow shown is not something that appears in any revision. It could be that "Dear friends" was automatically removed when the OP posted the question, or was removed after the question has been posted from a background process. The reason why Stack Overflow showed that is a mystery.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Fair enough. My apologies for my assumption. ;)

Comment: Another example of this is here: [Monitor process start in the system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293624/monitor-process-start-in-the-system). But I'm afraid I'm about to clobber it again...

Comment: @TheEstablishment Hah, I see. :) Ah well, clobber it I'd say. Not much else that can be done about it I guess.

Comment: What happened [10 minutes ago](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xB5kZ.png)? I dont see any change.

Comment: @AsheeshR... what do you mean? A Community bump perhaps?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My best guess here is that when [Jeff clobbered these kinds of greetings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/93989#93989) it was only done on the source text, and the pre-cooked HTML for that question was never regenerated.

This would have resulted in some phantom text which would not have appeared in the revisions since they are generated on-the-fly, nor in the underlying source when you went to edit.

However, discrepancies in some [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/9126) [edits](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/9126) that [awoodland](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/153020/awoodland) [found](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/884294#884294) suggest that the HTML *was* regenerated, given that the greeting text no longer appears in the current (since untouched) version of those posts, but is (presumably incorrectly) listed as being added by the suggested edit because it was once part of the source. So, I'm not positive either way.

<sub>P.S. - Just so no one doubts you, I also saw the text you were describing prior to Cody Gray's edit</sub>

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable explanation I guess. It was a curious one. :)

Comment: This would be my guess, as well.

Comment: Tim, you are correct - case closed.