# Incompatibility between shown question and text when editing

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Edit source differs from question view? Or are we each other's friends now?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123981/edit-source-differs-from-question-view-or-are-we-each-others-friends-now)

I just came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530933/dirent-h-in-visual-studio-2010-or-2008), which I immediately started to edit for better formatting. The strange thing that I saw is this:

This is the way the question is shown:

[image]

Notice the `Hi` in the beginning of the question.

When you edit the question though, this is what you see:

[image]

At first I thought someone edited the text right when I clicked, so I canceled. The `Hi` is still there. CTRL+F5 also didn't change anything. Logging out and clicking `Improve this question` again showed the exact same thing.

I canceled the edit so that this bug could be tried by others and fixed and I wouldn't accidentally make the bug go away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system is set to remove these generic greetings at the begining of posts. -  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/172936.

Perhaps this cleanup functionality is also executed when editing posts.

Comment: In this case it's the first explanation, but because the post hasn't been rebaked since the replacement was done on the source ([the revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5530933/revisions) shows the correct version)