# Question view out of sync with question source

Tags: bug, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Edit source differs from question view? Or are we each other’s friends now?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123981/edit-source-differs-from-question-view-or-are-we-each-others-friends-now)

[A question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3891831/209139) opens with the word *Hello*. I went to edit that (and make a few other changes, such as removing the thanks at the end, and tidying some grammar), and found that the word *Hello* is not in the text there of the edit box. Is this some sort of caching issue?

Comment: That's definitely a bug.  The hello should be automatically removed when the question is posted, but I have noticed that it doesn't always work correctly if the hello forms part of the first sentence.

Comment: It's because it is removed from the history of the post, but the post is still rendered as it was before the removal. You can just do edit the post, and the word vanishes.

Comment: I do not even see "hello" in the revision history from 2010

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA You don't see it: It is removed using code. (In other words, revisions are not created.) I noticed the same thing on Drupal Answers, and asked on the meta over there. Something along those lines was what a developer told me.